# Source and destination ports for passive FTP

Tags: ftp

I am having trouble figuring out the source and destination ports to put in port forwarding rule to allow an external FTP client to connect to **vsftpd** file server on the green network.

I am working on virtual machines, the client to server connection and file transfer is fine if put on the same internal network, but if the server is behind a firewall, the connection is made, but directory listing is not successful.

If I used the command line program ftp, I get the message 425 Failed to establish connection. Although I have specified the **pasv_min_port** and **pasv_max_port** to be 40000 and 40100 respectively in vsfpd, a wireshark analysis shows that the client doesn't any port of this range! On the server firewall, I have created a port forwarding rule to allow communications from 40000:40100 port range, that is the source port, the destination port is 21.

Comment: which port is used then? Does Wireshark see the PASV port that's assigned? Or is the client going for port 22, ftp-data? Second many firewall's (including Linux's netfiler) have specific helper modules for dealing with FTP ports  i.e. `nf_nat_ftp` and `nf_conntrack_ftp` in Linux kernels.

Comment: The ports used by the clients are in the range of 30000 to 60000. Port 22 does not appear at all.

Comment: and you did restart vsftpd after changing the configuration?

Comment: Yes, I don't forget that :)

Comment: The last packet that appears before the error messages is a LIST request.

Comment: Is your client behind NAT?

Comment: Yes, it is behind a firewall, which works like a NAT. But all outgoing traffic is allowed on that firewall.

Comment: You need to forward ports 40000-40100 on your server firewall.

Comment: You mean put this port range in the source port field, I have already done that!

Comment: Is server behind NAT firewall or only behind firewall?

Comment: Do you see either a PASV command from the client in the wireshark capture (requesting passive FTP port) or a PORT command (for the classical way)

Comment: The server is behind a firewall with external IP in one subnet and the protected network in another, isn't that a NAT Firewall?

Comment: @HBruijn I see the PASV command in Wireshark, that is in one packet, the next is "Entering Passive mode (192, 168)". I don't know what these numbers mean?!

Comment: Mohamed, if you use firewall external IP address to connect to (with ftp client), it is probably NAT. In any case, you have to do the same thing you did with port 21 (just create copy of '21' rule, and change 21 with 40000, both in source and destination!)

Comment: I have created another rule, source port same as the original rule 40000:401000, destination port is 40000. The firewall I am using is dedicated Linux OS, IPFire, it returned "Source port in use".

Comment: I have read this http://www.moreofless.co.uk/ftp-connects-no-directory-listing-command-passive/ it says that passive mode only uses one channel, so I don't have to create another rule with another source and destination.

Comment: Join the chat room please: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15580/source-and-destination-ports-for-passive-ftp

Comment: @dusan.bajic I am there now.